# Diet for fasting in hinduism

Tags: scripture, food, fasting

There is a [mention of fast](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b072.htm) in Mahabharata, Anusasana Parva about fasting which is continued for twenty-eight days, which is the maximum number of days of fasting.

> That man who having fasted for eight and twenty days eats a single
> meal on the twenty-ninth day, and bears himself in this way for a full
> year, adhering all the while to truthfulness of speech, attains to
> auspicious regions of great happiness that are worshipped by celestial
> Rishis and royal sages.

My question is, are there any diet plans for fasting which may be prolonged for such long days in scriptures. Are there any books which deal with such a diet?

If there are any references that these types of fasting are valid for Dwapara Yuga only, then what is the diet plan for fasting for the maximum number of days that is allowed in kali yuga.

Comment: It can certainly be done in kaliyuga, many jain take such vows in which fasting is there for 40+ days

Comment: Chandrayana vrat is one such vrata done for a whole month, Taptakruchra vrata, Ati kruchra vrat, Santapan kruchra vrat, the longest vrata is Chaturmasa vrata of 4 months (which started yesterday), Mandala vrat of 40 days, 16 days Mahalaxmi vrata, Prajapatya vrata, there is even a vrata done before Soma yagna which is for 1 year long. And there are many such more long term vratas. To be precise these vratas are for Kaliyug, as most of them are prayaschit vrat, so u knw Kaliyugi jeev needs them the most.